# In typeorm with replication, am I hitting the master instance whenever I am inside an EntityManager transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, race-condition, typeorm, amazon-aurora

I am having some race condition issues with an Aurora PostgreSQL DB hosted on AWS RDS. An example similar to what is happening is:

1. A Group table has a column `userEntranceLimits`.
2. A UserEntrance table has a column `userId` and a column `groupId`.
3. The `count` of a UserEntrance's distinct users for a specific group may not exceed the group's `userEntranceLimits`.
4. Inside a transaction for creating a new UserEntrance, I check if the current count of UserEntrances for that group is >= the limit.
5. If it is not, I proceed to create a new UserEntrance.
6. In some rare occasions, a group appears with more UserEntrances than its limit.

I initially thought that the race condition was because of out-of-sync read replicas. However, if I am understanding [this part](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.2.24/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts#L130) of typeorm's code correctly, the transactions will always execute in master. Is that right? If that's the case, then I suppose the actual solution to the race condition is changing the isolation level of the transaction to something else, e.g. `SERIALIZABLE`. Is any of this that I'm thinking true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use it in way described in [typeorm docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/9300710097f1f0343defc3f86becb1b2a05d32d4/docs/transactions.md) calling directly `entityManager.transaction()` or `@Transaction()` decorator and if you use connection, provided by transaction, then **YES**, transactions are using master.

As I debugged typeorm sources, while starting transaction, `entityManager.queryRunner` is `undefined`. So as per [EntityManager implementation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/9300710097f1f0343defc3f86becb1b2a05d32d4/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts#L130), queryRunner will be created for each transaction with no replication mode provided, so default (master) will be used.

So problem is more probable in your logic than in transaction configuration.